# Updating rails to 3.1.1 i get uninitialized constant Product::RAILS_ROOT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, root

After updating from 3.0.1 to 3.1.1 my application according the relevant [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1) i seem to get this:

uninitialized constant Product::RAILS_ROOT

Product is my main object

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Rails.root
```

add `to_s` if you need it as a string!

Answer (score 6):

`RAILS_ROOT`no longer exists. Use `Rails.root` instead.

Comment: Is this supposed to be in enviroment.rb or what?